# Using inline Markdown within a LaTeX table

Tags: tables, markdown

I'm trying to embed inline Markdown text within a LaTeX table, but no matter what I try, I always seem to get cryptical errors (I am a total novice with LaTeX, so they might be rather obvious actually).

Here is a minimum example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{markdown}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{markdown}
This __works__
\end{markdown}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|}
This works & 
\begin{itemize}
\item This
\item works
\end{itemize} &
\begin{markdown}
This does __not__
\end{markdown} \\
\end{tabularx} % <------ Error "Argument of ^^M has an extra }"

\end{document}
```

Whenever and however I try to include a Markdown environment within a table, I get errors like `% Error "Argument of ^^M has an extra }`. I can only guess something is not fitting together. Any hints on how to do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, the same result could be achieved by standard `tabular` environment with `p{width}` column-type, if you can't compile it with `tabularx`. Unfortunately, you have to manually workout all the column

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{markdown}
\usepackage{array}


\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{
        | p{\dimexpr(0.33\linewidth - 2\tabcolsep - 1.33\arrayrulewidth)}
        | p{\dimexpr(0.33\linewidth - 2\tabcolsep - 1.33\arrayrulewidth)}
        | p{\dimexpr(0.34\linewidth - 2\tabcolsep - 1.34\arrayrulewidth)}
        |
    }
    This works
        & Something here \begin{itemize}
            \item This
            \item works
        \end{itemize}
        & Something else \begin{markdown}
            This works
        \end{markdown} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I was sure I had tried a normal tabular at some point, but apparently I didn't do it the right way.

In the meantime I figured out that Markdown causes the same errors when used in commands & Co, there seems to be some more general issue with it.